# TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'x'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

Tensorflow 1.10 on Google Colab (python 2.7) or my local system (python 3.6)
Using sample code from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras
Code is

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

data = np.random.random((1000, 32))
labels = np.random.random((1000, 10))
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
dataset1 = dataset1.batch(32)
dataset1 = dataset1.repeat()

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset1, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

Throws the following error:

```
    Error TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'x'.

packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    544                   "%s type %s of argument '%s'." %
    545                   (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(attrs[input_arg.type_attr]).name,
--> 546                    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
    547 
    548           types = [values.dtype]

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'x'.
```

Comment: Try casting your input data and labels to `float32` with `data.astype(np.float32)`.

Comment: I tried this by casting all columns using tf.cast to float64 & float32, then it gave error "list index out of range"

Comment: I could not get dataset to work as input to Keras model.  In tensorflow 1.10

Comment: changing  data = np.random.random((2000,32))
data.astype(np.float32)   Error \site-packages\tensorflow\python\ keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, ..., verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    175   indices_for_conversion_to_dense = []
    176   for i in range(len(feed)):
--> 177     if issparse is not None and issparse(ins[i]) and not K.is_sparse(feed[i]):    178       indices_for_conversion_to_dense.append(i)  IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and I assume the default data type used in the `model` is `float32` while that of `numpy` is `float64`, and `from_tensor_slices` retains that type. To fix it, just change your code:

```
data = np.random.random((1000,32))
labels = np.random.random((1000,10))
```

to

```
data = np.random.random((1000,32)).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.random.random((1000,10)).astype(np.float32)
```

But I do think as a piece of sample code in its tutorial, tensorflow should make sure it runs.

Update: There is a closed issue related to this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22207

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar problem. I use this code snippet.

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
          loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy)
```

I guess the loss function in Keras only requires 'float' type (I didn't check the source code). To solve this problem, I add one more Layer at the end of the output layer.

```
decoder_outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(x, 'float32'), name='change_to_float')(decoder_outputs)
```

Hope this will help.